# Creating a foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I am currently creating a shopping basket for a website but at the moment I can only get it to work if I echo each product I have and the number of that product currently in the shopping basket as well as the other products that are in the database however it doesn't display a number. I'm attempting to create a foreach loop and then echo the results for each of the items in the basket rather than all my products. Below is my code as well as how it looks on my website. All my efforts in attempting to create a foreach loop seem to result in the foreach loop causing the whole script to fail. Any help on this issue would be very appreciated!

```
    if ($_GET[action]=="add") {
        $id=$_GET['radio_id'];
        $_SESSION['basket'.$id]++;

            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket1] Grundig G3 in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket2] Eton E5 in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket3] Eton E1 G3 in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket4] Morphy Richards DRM Radio G3 in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket5] TechniSat MultyRadio in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket6] Sony ICF-SW7600GR in your basket<br />";
            echo "You currently have $_SESSION[basket7] Sony AN-LP1 in your basket<br />";
         }
    else    {
            echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";
            }
```

The website displays this, as I add an item it then displays a number or increase a number depending on what item I add to the basket.

You currently have 2 Grundig G3 in your basket

You currently have 1 Eton E5 in your basket

You currently have Eton E1 G3 in your basket

You currently have Morphy Richards DRM Radio G3 in your basket

You currently have TechniSat MultyRadio in your basket

You currently have Sony ICF-SW7600GR in your basket

You currently have Sony AN-LP1 in your basket

---

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM radios WHERE radio_id=".$_GET[radio_id]) or die( mysqli_error($link));
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($_GET[action]=="add") {
    $id=$_GET['radio_id'];
    $_SESSION['basket'.$id]++;
        $manufacturer=$array['manufacturer'];

    foreach($_SESSION as $id => $amount){   

        if(strstr($id,'basket')){
             echo "You have $amount $manufacturer in your basket.<br>";
        }
        }
```

@vascowhite

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Nope, that's incorrect. It [will](http://3v4l.org/9noHq) expand.

Comment: Yes, it does expand. My issue isn't with this code as such its with adapting this code to create a foreach loop instead of just echoing each one.

Comment: @AmalMurali Oh wow - not only does it expand, but it *only* expands if you use the key as a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [`foreach()` loop](http://php.net/foreach), something like:-

```
$_SESSION['basket1'] = 2;
$_SESSION['basket2'] = 4;
$_SESSION['basket3'] = 10;
$_SESSION['someothervalue'] = 'test';

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Obviously all the above is just test code.
    foreach($_SESSION as $key => $amount){

```
    if(strstr($key, 'basket')){
        echo "You have $amount whatevers in your basket.<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
array (size=4)
  'basket1' => int 2
  'basket2' => int 4
  'basket3' => int 10
  'someothervalue' => string 'test' (length=4)
You have 2 whatevers in your basket.
You have 4 whatevers in your basket.
You have 10 whatevers in your basket.
```

Comment: Ive implemented your code, I now however am having a problem displaying individual properties for example the product name. 

if ($_GET[action]=="add") {
 $id=$_GET['radio_id'];
 $_SESSION['basket'.$id]++;
 
foreach($_SESSION as $id => $amount){

    if(strstr($id,'basket')){
        echo "You have $amount $array[manufacturer] in your basket.<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
} 

That's the code I'm now using im just wondering if there is a way to display properties for individual items instead of them all displaying the same one.
@vascowhite

Comment: Is the manufacturer information stored in $_SESSION? If you could edit the result of var_dump($_SESSION) into your question it would help me answer.

Comment: No the manufacturer information is stored in an array but Im having problems linking the manufacturer with the correct id.

Comment: Please put the code into your question, it is hard to read in a comment.

Comment: No, don't do that, it isn't an answer, it is part of your question. FFS!

Comment: You obviously don't understand what you are doing and you need to learn how to program. I can't teach you, so I'm sorry, but I can't help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else the code as written:

```
$_SESSION[basket1]
```

doesn't have brackets around the index so it'll be trying to render that basket1 as a constant.